# How to run Nvidia GeForce on AWS EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to set up cloud gaming using Moonlight on AWS. One of the requirements for Moonlight is NVIDIA GeForce Experience (GFE) 2.1.1 or higher.

GeForce is not starting in any of the AMI's available with NVIDIA Graphics card.
Error Message: **wlanapi.dll is missing**

please help me with the AMI selection on which GeForce works or with any other idea to build a cloud gaming solution.

AMI used: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07STLTHM8?qid=1576752275140&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title

Tried this solution as well: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-play-pubg-on-aws-db2e75fa599b

Answer (score 3):

This error is fixed with installing Wireless LAN service

Go to Server Manager -> Manage -> Add Roles and Features

Then go Next,next, next all the way to features and then at the bottom you will see the Wireless Lan Service. Click on it and install it.

That solved the problem for me.

[image]